# Regular expression exclude hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I'm highlighting some text, like so:

```
var newHTML = oldHTML.replaceAll(filter, "<span class='highlight'>" + filter + "</span>");
```

I have this function that I use to replace html content.

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
var target = this;
return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

Because I don't want to brake any hyperlinks (but I want to keep other html tags to keep the formatting) I need to exclude `<a href>` tags. Somebody knows how?

Edit, an example input & output to clarify:

input

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">youtube</a>
```

highlight youtube text only (only match the second "youtube")

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><span class="highlight">youtube</span></a>
```

Edit 2, found it - this the regex I need.

```
youtube(?!([^<]+)?>)
```

Somehow it doesn't work in my function (no matches for

```
input.replaceAll("youtube","<span class='highlight'>youtube</span>")
```

). Any guesses why?

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
var target = this;
//return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);

var regex = "/" + search + "(?!([^<]+)?>)/g";
return target.replace(regex, replacement);
```

};

Comment: <\s*a[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*a> is your regex 
Do you want me to write a complete answer ?

Comment: Sure, but this regex ain't it.

Comment: this regex will match all <a> tag....is this what you wanted to do ? Please see here :
https://www.regextester.com/27540 
If this is okay for you tell me and I will write this as an answer

Comment: you should write clear input and output so we can give right answer

Comment: Edited with examples.

Comment: I see you found your answer. You can construct like: return target.replace(new RegExp(search + '(?!([^<]+)?>)', 'gi'), replacement);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the politics of the Javascript community at SO, but maybe the downvotes are because it would be best to parse the HTML as HTML, rather than string/regex manipulation. That way, you can check easily for a TextNode and then replace the contents of the text nodes.

That said, this Regex should be a start for you:

```
(?<=>[^<]*)youtube
```

Be aware that this uses Lookbehinds which are not supported by all browsers AFAIK, so this might be useful for Chrome etc if you have some project work to do via strings...

Comment: I can't use Text, because I add a class to the pattern of the text, making it HTML to replace - so I need original HTML in the first place. Or maybe I'm not getting it. Your regex is also working, but not in a function, maybe I made a mistake there, see my edit 2.

Comment: I see you found your answer. You can construct like: return target.replace(new RegExp(search + '(?!([^<]+)?>)', 'gi'), replacement);